# How to call a function for every received video frame in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to call a function for every video frame from my laptop camera. Here's what I tried:

mainwindow.h

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QVideoProbe>
#include <QCamera>
#include <QMediaRecorder>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void processFrame(const QVideoFrame &frame);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QVideoProbe *probe;
    QCamera* camera;
    QMediaRecorder* recorder;
};
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    probe = new QVideoProbe;
    camera = new QCamera;
    recorder = new QMediaRecorder(camera);

    connect(probe, SIGNAL(videoFrameProbed(QVideoFrame)), this, SLOT(processFrame(QVideoFrame)));

    probe->setSource(recorder);

    camera->setCaptureMode(QCamera::CaptureVideo);
    camera->start();
    recorder->record();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::processFrame(const QVideoFrame &frame){
    //do something
}
```

I would like to have the processFrame function called every time a new video frame is detected by the prob signal. The code runs with no errors, but processFrame doesn't seem to be called (I update a label's text in the processFrame function just to test).

probe->setSource(recorder) returns false, which, according to the qt documentation for QVideoProbe class, means the media recorder instance does not support monitoring video. I'm not sure if this means my hardware is not supported (built in webcam on windows 10), or if the media recorder/camera objects were not set up properly

Comment: Check return value of the `connect(probe,...` method. Be also note not all platforms support `QVideoProbe`. See https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5.13_Multimedia_Backends#Supported_media_player_features_by_backend

Comment: Did you check if the camera actually works? There is a [camera example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimediawidgets-camera-example.html) in QtCreator

Comment: @pptaszni yea my camera works with that example

Comment: @VladimirBershov the connect returns true

Comment: probe->setSource(recorder) is returning false

Comment: Your code works for me. [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideoprobe.html#setSource-1) it's written that `setSource` returns false if recorder does not support monitoring video. Try to investigate the state of your recorder and your `QCamera`.

Comment: @pptaszni the state for the recorder is stopped and the status is unavailable, and the state for the QCamera is active and the status is active. it seems the recorder is not compatible with my hardware?